# How to show a random variable is bounded (Ex 2.5.5 Roman Vershynin High dimensional Probability)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have that $${\rm E}[\exp(\lambda^2X^2)] \leq \exp(K \lambda^2)$$
for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and some $K\gt 0$.

Show that $X$ must be a bounded random variable.

This is Ex 2.5.5 Roman Vershynin High dimensional Probability.

Comment: Hint: Markov's inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Ee^{\lambda^{2}(X^{2}-K)} \leq 1$. Hence $Ee^{\lambda^{2}(X^{2}-K)} I_A \leq 1$ where $A$ is th event $(|X| >\sqrt K)$. Let $\lambda \to \infty$ to see (by Monotone Convergence Theorem) that $P(A)=0$. Hence $|X| \leq \sqrt K$ a.s..